# Are the Metal version of CIFilters available on A7 processors

Tags: ios, avfoundation, metal

I'm writing a camera app that applies Core Image filters to the video output of the camera and displays the results using a Metal render pipeline within a MTKView. This all seems to be working fine but I don't have an iPhone 5S or iPad Mini 2 or 3 to test if it works on A7 processors. Do the CIFilters make use of the Metal Performance Shaders that are only available on A8 processors and later? It is not very obvious from the documentation.

I am using the filters CIColorCube and CIPhotoEffectMono.

Answer (score 0):

MPS does not work on A7 processors, the bottom line is that the A7 is just not fast enough to handle real workloads, A8 and later processors are much much faster, so Apple just decided to not support the A7 for this functionality. I cannot see how this would ever change since it is a hardware issue.

Comment: Maybe my question isn't clear enough because you are the second person to repeat what I have already stated in the question. I am asking do these filters use MPS, not if it is available on A7 processors

Comment: Could you provide a github link to working code that uses the CIColorCube and CIPhotoEffectMono, I could test it on an A7 device but working example code would be needed in order to do that.